# What are all the different weapon colours and their meanings?

Tags: diablo-iii

What do the colours of weapon names and their effects generally mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is for items (including weapons) in general. The item colour indicates the quality and/or the purpose of the item. The information comes mostly from [Diablo Wiki](http://www.diablowiki.net/Items#Item_Quality_and_Color), but some of it has changed since beta.

- **Legendary Items**: Orange
- **Rare Items**: Yellow
- **Set Items**: Green
- **Magical Items**: Blue
- **Normal Items**: White
- **Junk Items**: Gray
- **Quest/Lore items**: Green
- **Potions and Artisan Crafting items**: Light Blue

Comment: Might I point out that Runes no longer exist as items? Your info is out of date.

Comment: You are right. I remember runes being automatically unlocked as you progress through the game. Removed...

Comment: @JamesJiao "Set items do not exist as a special sub-type of item in Diablo III" Are you sure? [The Diablo 3 site has a category for them under each weapon type](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/axe-1h/#type=set).

Comment: Damn that wiki. Looks like I have to get off my lazy ass and do some reason research.

Comment: Added new light blue quality.

Comment: @CronosDage you might as well mark this one as the answer since it is all 100% accurate :p